# Create custom API with strapi

Tags: node.js, api, strapi

I've a content type called continent. Which we the name suggests contains all the information about each continents. Strapi already created API endpoints for me like

**continents/:id**

But I want to search the continent by it's name since the general user won't be able to search by id

I've created the endpoint

**continents/:continent_name**

I've also created custom controller following documentation

```
const { sanitizeEntity } = 
requiree('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {


async findOne(ctx) {
const { continent_name } = ctx.params;

const entity = await 
strapi.services.continent.findOne({ 
continent_name 
});
return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: 
continents });
```

And also exposed the API to public
But doesn't seem to anything
Just returns error

How am I supposed to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, you don't need to extend the model controller. You can just pass the continent name as a `query param` . For example, your url could be something like `base_url/continent?continent_name=Asia`.

For the code mentioned in the question, there is an issue, the model name should be `strapi.models.continent` and not `continents`. Also in the first line `requiree('strapi-utils')`, you have an extra e in the require. I am assuming that was just a typo.